# Subversion // installed and set, but fail to connect

Tags: centos, subversion

I aim to get my own SVN server.

I installed Subversion, all had been ok.
I configured it

```
<Location /myrepo>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /svn/adlsvn  

        #For any else operations, require an authenticated user.
        # Limit write permission to list of valid users.

        <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
              # Require SSL connection for password protection.
              # SSLRequireSSL

              AuthType Basic
              AuthName "Authorization Realm"
              AuthUserFile /etc/svn-users
              Require valid-user
        </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

And finally I ran **svnserver**

```
svnserver -d
```

But... http://mydomain.com/myrepo display 404,
and Tortoise, SmartSVN and so third say :

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://usertest@mydomain.com/myrepo'
The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 1: no element found (http://usertest@mydomain.com/myrepo)
```

Please help... a matter of port ? security ?

Comment: I think you have to enable http access. Normal access is on port 3690 for the svn protocol (but check I fortunately was able to stop svn ten years ago and haven't looked back).

Comment: If you're using Apache, you don't need the `svnserver` process.